# From file as a string to a reference to a file in msbuild

Tags: msbuild

### Background

As `CopyLocal=true` causes a lot of build slowdowns as projects and solutions grow in size (see [here](http://%E2%80%A2%09http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/partitioning-your-code-base-through-.net-assemblies-and-visual-studio-projects/)), I'm trying to figure out a good convention-based solution that works with nuget and performs an incremental build, only copying the assemblies and their related files, liked pdb's, when necessary.

Here's what I have so far:

```
<!--
    Assumptions: each project copies all of its required dependencies
    to the same output directory.

    I have two basic options here. I can look at @(Reference) and pull
    the HintPath information to copy the correct assemblies, or I can
    use @(ReferencePath) which gives me a list of all the different
    required assemblies. The latter doesn't allow me to distinguish
    system ones from ones that I have explicitly included. I could
    probably include the non-system ones by filtering to some sub-
    directory of the solution.
-->
<ItemGroup>
  <_AssembliesToCopy Include="..\..\packages\Moq.4.0.10827\lib\NET40\Moq.dll" />
  <_AssembliesToCopy Include="..\..\packages\NUnit.2.5.10.11092\lib\nunit.framework.dll" />
  <!-- ... -->
</ItemGroup>
<PropertyGroup>
  <AfterBuildDependsOn>
    $(AfterBuildDependsOn);
    CopyReferencedAssemblies;
    CopyFilesRelatedToReferencedAssemblies
  </AfterBuildDependsOn>
</PropertyGroup>
<Target Name="AfterBuild" DependsOnTargets="$(AfterBuildDependsOn)" />
<Target Name="CopyFilesRelatedToReferencedAssemblies"
  Inputs="@(_ReferenceRelatedPaths)"
  Outputs="@(_ReferenceRelatedPaths->'$(OutputPath)%(Filename)%(Extension)')"
  DependsOnTargets="ResolveReferences"
  >
  <Copy
      SourceFiles="@(_ReferenceRelatedPaths)"
      DestinationFiles="@(_ReferenceRelatedPaths->'$(OutputPath)%(Filename)%(Extension)')"
      UseHardlinksIfPossible="true"
      />
</Target>

<Target Name="CopyReferencedAssemblies"
    Inputs="@(_AssembliesToCopy)"
    Outputs="@(_AssembliesToCopy->'$(OutputPath)%(Filename)%(Extension)')"
    DependsOnTargets="ResolveReferences"
    >
  <Copy
      SourceFiles="@(_AssembliesToCopy)"
      DestinationFiles="@(_AssembliesToCopy->'$(OutputPath)%(Filename)%(Extension)')"
      UseHardlinksIfPossible="true"
      />
</Target>
```

This works exactly as I need it to. On a new build, it copies the files:

```
CopyReferencedAssemblies:
  Creating hard link to copy "..\..\packages\Moq.4.0.10827\lib\NET40\Moq.dll" to "..\..\build\bin\Debug\Moq.dll".
  Creating hard link to copy "..\..\packages\NUnit.2.5.10.11092\lib\nunit.framework.dll" to "..\..\build\bin\Debug\nunit.framework.dll".
CopyFilesRelatedToReferencedAssemblies:
Building target "CopyFilesRelatedToReferencedAssemblies" partially, because some output files are out of date with respect to their input files.
  Creating hard link to copy "c:\Project\packages\Moq.4.0.10827\lib\NET40\Moq.pdb" to "..\..\build\bin\Debug\Moq.pdb".
  Creating hard link to copy "c:\Project\packages\Moq.4.0.10827\lib\NET40\Moq.xml" to "..\..\build\bin\Debug\Moq.xml".
  Creating hard link to copy "c:\Project\packages\NUnit.2.5.10.11092\lib\nunit.framework.xml" to "..\..\build\bin\Debug\nunit.framework.xml".
```

And when the files are up-to-date, it doesn't do anything:

```
CopyReferencedAssemblies:
Skipping target "CopyReferencedAssemblies" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
CopyFilesRelatedToReferencedAssemblies:
Skipping target "CopyFilesRelatedToReferencedAssemblies" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
```

## Question

The problem with my current solution is that I've had to **duplicate** the value already provided by `HintPath` included in the project references:

```
<Reference Include="Moq">
  <HintPath>..\..\packages\Moq.4.0.10827\lib\NET40\Moq.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>False</Private>
</Reference>
```

Became an extra:

```
<_AssembliesToCopy Include="..\..\packages\Moq.4.0.10827\lib\NET40\Moq.dll" />
```

How can I convert the set of strings found in `%(Reference.HintPath)` to file references?  Ideally, I'd like a command that I can just assign to `_AssembliesToCopy`:

```
<_AssembliesToCopy Include="{{Change %(Reference.HintPath) to file ref}}"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this not work:

```
<Target Name="MyTarget">
  <ItemGroup>
    <_AssembliesToCopy Include="%(Reference.HintPath)" />
  </ItemGroup>
  ...then the Copy task using @(_AssembliesToCopy)
</Target>
```

Comment: `%(Reference.HintPath)` is not interpreted, it ends up a string literal :(.

Comment: It should be <_AssembliesToCopy Include="@(Reference)" />

Comment: 1.  It should not be what Ludwo suggests, that will only copy the "Include" values in the Reference items to the new item array, not what is wanted at all.  2.  I just tried this and %(Reference.HintPath) is interpreted.  Check your spelling and syntax very carefully, or paste your exact code into your question and I'll help you diagnose it.

Comment: In looking at yours more carefully (shame on me for not doing so earlier), you have the `ItemGroup` defined within a Target where mine is global. I presume that's the problem? Now investigating.

Comment: Details: I initially went with a global `ItemGroup`, but it didn't get expanded. Part of the main thing I wanted to accomplish was to have it support an incremental build so it wouldn't copy the assemblies and related files every time it ran. To fix, I removed the global `ItemGroup` reference and then added an additional dependency to my `AfterBuildDependsOn` that ran before my copy targets that created the dynamic `ItemGroup` as you demonstrated. Once done, everything worked beautifully. Thank you!